# Number of Session remains the same after users logout

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7

With performance counter to observe the "**Sessions Total**", I found the # of session stays the same after users logout. Is this expected behavior in IIS7?

Here is the logout implementation:

```
Session.Clear();
Session.Abandon();
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Thanks.

Comment: How is user logout implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking at the wrong counter:

- **Sessions Total** is the total number of sessions since the web application was started (this number will never go down, except if you restart the web app)
- **Sessions Active** is the current number of active sessions (<- this is what you want to look at)

Answer (score 1):

Session is NOT inherently tied to forms authentication, if that's what you're using. Are you calling `Session.Abandon()` when a user logs out of your app? Even so, if a user discontinues using the app without signing out, the session will remain open until it expires. The session expiration time can be set in the web.config.

Answer (score 1):

One session might be destroyed but another one is created shorty there after. Just because the user isn't authenticated any longer doesn't mean that he or she doesn't have a session state.

It's very likely that the session is destroyed but upon the next request (which i presume is on the same domain/server causes the session id to be reused and thus creating an empty session state with the same session id)

**All this is of course assuming that you redirect to a location within the same web site immediately after logging someone out.**

Answer (score 1):

Do you logout your user like this?

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
HttpContext.Current.User = null;
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```